# Angular 2 AOT - "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined error"

Tags: angular, rollup, angular2-aot

I having a problem running Angular 2 app compiled for AoT with Rollup using instructions from angular.io docs (link [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html))

The compilation process goes OK as far as I can tell though I'm getting this as the only output:

```
⚠️   'default' is imported from external module 'rollup' but never used

'initializeApp' is not exported by 'node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js'
'initializeApp' is not exported by 'node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js'
'app' is not exported by 'node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js'
'auth' is not exported by 'node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js'
'database' is not exported by 'node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js'
'database' is not exported by 'node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js'
```

The **build.js** is created and I have my index.html pointing to it and other required files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ahead of time compilation</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="dist/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.8.9/zone.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
<script src="dist/build.js"></script>
</html>
```

However, when I run my app in the browser I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined**.

Any suggestions on how to resolve it?